# The graph of the function $y=\log_bx$ passes through the point $(729,6)$. Determine $b$.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

The graph of the function $y=\log_bx$ passes through the point $(729,6)$. Determine $b$.

Could someone show me a solution that is similar to mine if it is correct?

$\log_b 729 = 6$

$729 = b^6$

$b = 729^{1/6} = 3$

Comment: Your solution is good.

Comment: For help typing math here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is fine. There are of course six different sixth roots of 729, but only one which is a positive real number.

Answer (score 1):

After solving $$b=729^{1/6}$$ you get $$b=\pm 3$$

but as $b>0$ , base log is always positive and not equal to 1 . So, we get only $b=3$ as solution,